# Как получить доступ к полю JSON (python, django)

Tags: python, json, django

Впервые работаю с Python, буквально пару строчек кода надо написать, для работы кое-какой системы. Проблема вот в чем. Есть JSON-response от сервера, мне надо получить значение поля в нем.

```
[{u'message': {u'chat': {u'first_name': u'Иван',
                     u'id': 1,
                     u'last_name': u'Иван',
                     u'type': u'private',
                     u'username': u'ivan'},
           u'date': 1,
           u'entities': [{u'length': 6,
                          u'offset': 0,
                          u'type': u'bot_command'}],
           u'from': {u'first_name': u'Иван',
                     u'id': 1,
                     u'last_name': u'Иван',
                     u'username': u'Иван'},
           u'message_id': 2,
           u'text': u'/start'},
u'update_id': 1}]
```

Итак, мне надо получить значение, к примеру, поля 'first_name'. Как мне его получить? Тут, я так понял, двойной список. Если бы был одинарный, то я бы мог получить значение поля first_name вот так:

```
response['first_name']
```

здесь же так не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
response[0]['message']['chat']['first_name']
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! :)